# How to make requests to Amadeus API? Got Network Error

Tags: api, error-handling, sdk, amadeus

I've just registered my test app and got Api key and Api secret. I'm trying to send request using Python SDK:

```
from amadeus import Client, ResponseError

amadeus1 = Client(
client_id='my_API_key_here',
client_secret='my_secret_key_here'
)

response = amadeus1.reference_data.locations.airports.get(longitude=49.000, latitude=2.55)
print(response.data)
```

I receive Network Error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

The problem came from an SSL certificate issue on the dev environment.

---

I cannot reproduce the problem, the API seems to work. Your example returns an empty array because the data in the test environment are limited. For this API the countries covered are: United States, Spain, United Kingdom, Germany & India.

So if you try with London's geolocation

> response = amadeus1.reference_data.locations.airports.get(longitude=0.1278, latitude=51.5074)

As you can see, the response contains data.

But I don't have a Network issue.
If you still face the issue please contact our support through our portal, share your username so we can check your API Key and API Secret.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried to change location but got the same error. Could it be a problem with an access token? As I didn't get how to deal with it using SDK.

Comment: Could you please send me your information at developers@amadeus.com so I can investigate in details. Please send me the exact code you are using too.

Comment: Getting the same error. How was this resolved? It seems like a real burden to have to make my server ssl in development, no? I don't see this mentioned anywhere in docs.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem again a few days ago. My problem was sending requests from my local environment. It was trying to validate the SSL and that caused issues.

I solved it by including an 'unverified context' to be used by the `urlopen`. This should not be used in a production environment. It works making requests to both Amadeus test and production environments from my local machine.

```
import ssl


def ssl_disabled_urlopen(endpoint):
    context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
    return urlopen(endpoint, context=context)


amadeus = Client(
    client_id = '<client_id>',
    client_secret = '<client_secret>',
    http=ssl_disabled_urlopen
)
```